# Display tree-like structure of assembler code

Tags: assembly, tree

I am currently working a lot with assembler code and was wondering if anyone knew of some type of software or package that would allow to display the assembler code in a tree structure? I googled for it but haven't found anything really... I am looking for something that would display the code in a similar format to the tree utility that displays the tree structure of directories.
Any tips on this?

Comment: asm code doesn't have a hierarchical structure the way a directory tree does.  I have no idea what you'd expect it to look like, other than a degenerate tree with depth = 1 and every separate function being a child of the root note.  Or maybe two level root -> source file -> function.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [IDA Pro](http://img.appnee.com/appnee.com/IDA-Pro-4.png).

Comment: Actually I was thinking about something that shows in a tree like structure which address is accessed or jmped to from which other address, that kind of stuff...

Comment: @hidefromkgb Thank you that looks good!

Comment: @hidefromkgb Alternatively, there also is https://www.hopperapp.com/